# Prove equivalence of particular areas in generic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am a university student taking a course in Mathematics Teaching, and one assignment is the following problem, to be solved using only Euclidean geometry as is presented in Euclid's Elements. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start.

While I am required to present a very formalized solution, as if it were a proposition in Euclid's book, I am confident in my ability to produce it if I had just an idea for a solution to this problem.

Here is the problem:

> Consider a quadrilateral $ABCD$, and $M_1 ... M_4$ the midpoints of its sides $AB, ..., DA$ respectively.
>   Draw the segments $AM_3, BM_4, ...$ as in the picture.
>   Show that the triangles $t_1, ...., t_4$ have total area equal to that of the quadrilateral $q_1$

Thank you.

[image: ]]

Comment: Duplicate? ["Quadrilateral's area problem"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1401311/409).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wonder why it didn't show up on Google, or on the SE search. I guess searching for a specific problem is hard.

Comment: Searching is pretty tricky here. I knew I'd seen something like the problem before, so I searched "quadrilateral midpoint area" and looked through a few results. Luckily, it came up pretty quickly.